# In Android how can I find out the class that processes an Intent at runtime (logcat is fine)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have a large Android app that uses a bunch of implicit intents. I would like to debug and see what classes process each one of the Intents.

Say I have Intent A. Intent A is send. How can I trace in logcat what class processes this intent?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logcat messages yet?  Note that an app can't do this, only an ADB debug host or otherwise somewhat privileged system process.

Answer (score 1):

Add flag [Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION) to your intent.  The logcat output is tagged with `IntentResolver` at `Verbose` level.

Answer (score 0):

To know the class name of an intent, you can write this:

```
String className = getIntent().getComponent().getClassName();
Log.i("Class Name: ", className);
```

Comment: The question specifically said "implicit" intents, which by definition are those which do not specify a component, so none will be visible to the sender.   getIntent() would only work in the receiver, and if that is the posters app and running the code you suggest, it presumably already knows "who" it is... so in effect, your suggestion only works for the unusual case of trying to figure out which path of invocation was used to enter a single app.